# Vertx eventBus reference in javascript

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, event-bus, vert.x

I am running a spring boot server integrating vertx inside like below

In my spring boot application class

```
@Bean
public Vertx vertx() {
    return Vertx.vertx();
}
```

In my spring controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        eventBus.publish("CNotifications", "message sent : {}" + message_counter++);
    }
}
```

How to get a handle of the event bus on the client (angular) side? I have tried angular-vertx module like below

```
controllers.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope, vertxBus) {

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        vertxBus.registerHandler("CNotifications", function(message) {
            console.log('Received message ' + message);
        });
    });
});
```

But the error says no such function registerHandler. Is there another angular wrapper module for vertx that I can use? or can I fix this code above to make it work. I have added these below js in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/vertx/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/vertx/vertxbus-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/vertx/angular-vertx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked for several things..

**Vert.x in Spring Boot**

First of all: If you don't need Spring Boot, you can open the server directly with [Vert.x itself](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs_event_bus_bridge).

But if this setup is the requirement: Please have a look at the [full working official demo using Spring Boot by Vert.x itself at GitHub](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/springboot-example).

**Remark on element.ready**

You have used within a controller an `angular.element(document).ready`. That does not make any sense. If the controller has been called (by AJS), the document has been ready for some time obviously. For sure, it does not break your code, but it is not needed.

**AngularJS plugin**

The author of angular-vertx has [cancelled his work on this prototype/project](http://problemsolver-extraordinaire.blogspot.de/2014/09/vertx-and-angularjs.html).

If you need a nice wrapper in the AngularJS context, I would suggest a look at **my project** [angular-vertxbus](https://github.com/knalli/angular-vertxbus): it provides a reconnectable wrapper and a handy service api with promise support.